# Update geolocation field (SPFieldGeolocationValue) with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to update the latitude/longitude via powershell but can't get it to work.  I am basically hitting the bing service with an address retrieving the longitude/latitude then trying to assign those values to the geocode for the list object I am working with.

Here is a small snippet of my code I am testing with.

```
 $LIST_ITEM_TO_UPDATE['Geo Location'].Latitude = 10

 $LIST_ITEM_TO_UPDATE['Geo Location'].Longitude = 10

 $LIST_ITEM_TO_UPDATE.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check somewhat similar question @ [how to access programatically a geolocation column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105815/how-to-access-programatically-a-geolocation-column/105817)

Try this:

```
$val = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldGeolocationValue] $item['Geo Location'];
$val.Latitude = [double]10;
$val.Longitude = [double]10;
$item['Geo Location'] = $val;
$item.Update();
```

Also you can use [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) as in [the sample at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164050%28v=office.15%29.aspx#SP15addgeo_addlistitem):

> oListItem["location"] = "POINT (78.4 17.4)" ;

Comment: What about if I used CSOM / PnP PowerShell to do this ?

Comment: The msdn off course doesnt describe how to use the field in CAML

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using PnP PowerShell with the following:

```
Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity 1 -Values @{"GeoLocationField" =  "POINT(78.4 17.4)";}
```