# how to access programatically a geolocation column?

Tags: 2013

I have added in sharepoint 2013 a column of type geolocation to a list, and want to access it programatically from .net client object model to insert and update data. Do you have any code to show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luis,

You can use the following code to set GeoLocation field:

```
var oGeolocationValue = new SPFieldGeolocationValue();
oGeolocationValue.Latitude = (double)17.4;
oGeolocationValue.Longitude = (double)78.4;
oListItem["GeoField"] = oGeolocationValue;
```

And here is how you retrieve a value from GeoLocation field:

```
var geoVal = item["GeoField"] as SPFieldGeolocationValue;
if (geoVal != null)
{
    var lat = geoVal.Latitude;
    var lon = geoVal.Longitude;
    var mes = geoVal.Measure;
    var alt = geoVal.Altitude;
}
```

Further help:

[Add a list item with the Geolocation field value to a SharePoint list programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164050%28v=office.15%29.aspx#SP15addgeo_addlistitem)

[SPFieldGeolocationValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldgeolocationvalue%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: What about if I am using CSOM PowerShell ?  How do I do this using CSOM / PnP PowerShell ?